# How to prove $\lvert z \rvert \geq \Re(z)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, proof-writing

I try to prove
$$
\lvert z \rvert \geq \Re(z) \tag 1
$$
For a complex number $z= x+iy$ we have
\begin{align}
\lvert z \rvert &=\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \tag 2 \\
\lvert z \rvert^2 &=x^2+y^2 \tag 3
\end{align}
And for att real number $x$ we have
$$
\lvert x \rvert = \sqrt{x^2} \tag 4
$$
The proof:
A number squared is always non-negative, so we start with $y^2\geq 0$, i.e.
\begin{align}
y^2 &\geq 0 
\tag 5
\\
y^2 + x^2 &\geq x^2  
\tag 6
\\
\lvert z\rvert ^2 &\geq x^2 
\qquad (\text{from } (3))
\tag 7
\\
\sqrt{\lvert z\rvert ^2} &\geq \sqrt{x^2} 
\tag 8
\\
\lvert z \rvert &\geq x 
\qquad 
\tag 9
\\
\lvert z \rvert &\geq \Re(z)
\tag{10}
\end{align}

I don't know if $(9)$ is correct, should it instead be $\lvert z \rvert > \lvert x\rvert$, due to the absolute value in $(4)$? But, if so, I instead end up with $\lvert z \rvert \geq \lvert \Re(z) \rvert$?

Comment: Note that $\left| {\Re z} \right| \ge \Re z$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $|z|\geqslant |x|$. Then, use the fact that $|x|\geqslant x$.

Comment: The answer depends on where x and z are greater than one or between zero and one.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, that is, you proved correctly that $|z|\geqslant|\operatorname{Re}(z)|$. And, since $|\operatorname{Re}(z)|\geqslant\operatorname{Re}(z)$, you get that $|z|\geqslant\operatorname{Re}(z)$.